# A problem in quantum mechanics

Tags: calculus, physics

> The state vector $|\psi \rangle$ is defined in the matrix approach
> $$|\psi \rangle=\begin{pmatrix}
> \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ 
> -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
> \end{pmatrix}$$
> Find the average value of the observable $F$ in this state, if it corresponds to an operator with the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
> 5 &1-2i \\ 
>  1+2i&-4 
> \end{pmatrix}$

**My attempt:** The average value of the observable represented by the operator $F$ in the state $|\psi \rangle$ can be found using the formula
$$\langle F \rangle = \langle\psi|F|\psi\rangle$$

Let's write everything down in component form.

$$|\psi \rangle=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ 
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{pmatrix}, \quad F=\begin{pmatrix}
5 &1-2i \\ 
 1+2i&-4 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Now find the average value of the operator $F$ in the state $|psi \rangle$

$$F|\psi\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}
5 &1-2i \\ 
 1+2i&-4 
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ 
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
5\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+(1-2i)\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\\ 
 (1+2i)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-4\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
(5-1+2i)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ 
 (1+2i-4)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
(4+2i)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ 
 (-3+2i)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\langle\psi|F|\psi\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
(4+2i)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ 
 (-3+2i)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{pmatrix} = (4+2i)\frac{1}{2} - (3-2i)\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1+4i}{2} = \frac{1}{2}+2i$$

The average value of the observed $F$ in this state $|psi \rangle$ I got $\frac{1}{2}+2i$

**Was my reasoning and task correct? I would be grateful if you could check or correct the errors**

Comment: You must have made a mistake. Being an observable, $F$ is Hermitian, so its eigenvalues are real, as is its mean. If you check your calculations, the $-4$ in $1+2i-4$ is a sign error.

Comment: I believe you went wrong with $-4$ and $- \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ in the first step of evaluating $F|\psi \rangle$. Saying basically the same thing as J.G..

Comment: Indeed the correct computation for $F|\psi\rangle$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}4+2i\\5+2i\end{pmatrix}$, and the average value of $F$ is $-\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

It should be
$$F|\psi\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}
5 &1-2i \\ 
 1+2i&-4 
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ 
-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
5\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+(1-2i)\left(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\\ 
 (1+2i)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+4\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
(5-1+2i)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ 
 (1+2i+4)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
(4+2i)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ 
 (5+2i)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\langle\psi|F|\psi\rangle = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
(4+2i)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\ 
 (5+2i)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{pmatrix} = (4+2i)\frac{1}{2} - (5+2i)\frac{1}{2} = -\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: It turns out I made a mistake somewhere in the arithmetic (with a sign)